# xpath, function identifies classes by searching elements?

Tags: html, xpath

I'm a very new beginner with xpath and html. Is it possible to search an html for a text "xxxx" under in each class "authorbox" and if the class has it, automatically select the parent class tr.

< tr>

< td class="authorbox">

```
 < div class="regsn">

      < a href="/member/profile/xxxx" t="post-usersntxt">xxxx< /a>
```

....

and the table contiues with more

< tr>

< tr>

< tr>

### EDIT

This is the xpath I'm currently able to make

//td[@class='authorbox']

I don't really know how to search for text "xxxx" or select the parent tr if the text is found. I can select each table if I want to though, but it would be nice if it was more automatic.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show any of your attempts at creating the xpath? It would be a useful starting point to understand where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi. Thanks.  This is the xpath I'm currently able to make

//td[@class='authorbox']

I don't really know how to search for text "xxxx" or select the parent tr if the text is found. I can select each table if I want to though, but it would be nice if it was more automatic.

Comment: So, what exactly in the case of the provided XML do you want to be selected/retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//tr[td[@class='authorbox']
           //text()[contains(., 'xxxx')]
    ]
```

this selects any `tr` in the XML document that has a `td` child whose `class` attribute's string value is the string `"authorbox"` and that (the `td` child) has a text-node descendant whose string value is a string that contains `"xxxx"`.

**This may be made more precise**:

**If the text node descendant's string value must be *exactly* the string `"xxxx"`, then use**:

```
//tr[td[@class='authorbox']
           //text()[. = 'xxxx']
    ]
```

**If the string value of the text-node descendant shoud start with the string `"xxxx"`, use**:

```
//tr[td[@class='authorbox']
           //text()[starts-with(., 'xxxx')]
    ]
```

**If the string value of the text-node descendant shoud contains the string `"xxxx"` that is surrounded only by white-space, use**:

```
//tr[td[@class='authorbox']
           //text()[normalize-space(., 'xxxx')]
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks guys you are both angels.

Comment: @TokDoom: You are welcome. As for the angels, well, you have just realised that XPath is Heaven :)

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like you're halfway there. You just need to add a little beef to your predicate:

```
//tr[td/@class="authorbox" and td/div/a="xxxx"]
```

Also, if you want the `tr`, you can start with that as above, and push the `td` reference down into the predicate.

Comment: Thanks guys you are both angels.